# how to do code refactoring to reduce similar code in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

> Hello I am a newbie, I just started creating a project for quiz application.I have repeated code in my store and update
>   function,how can i reduce the duplication and write a cleaner code, any help will be appreciated

Thanks Nabeel

> This is my store method

```
public function store(Quiz $quiz, QuestionRequest $request)
     {  
        if($request->hasfile('image'))
        { 
            $file=$request->file('image');
            //Get File name with the extension
            $fileWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get Just File Name
            $filename = pathinfo($fileWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Get Just Extension
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //Filename to store
            $nameoffile = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //Upload Image
            $path = $file->move(public_path('images'),$nameoffile); 
            //$path = $file->storeAs('app/img/',$nameoffile); 
            $path = $nameoffile;
        }  
        else
        {
            $path=null;
        }

     }
```

This is my update method

```
public function update(Quiz $quiz,QuestionRequest $request,Question $question)
    {  
        if(is_null($question->imgpath))
        {
            if($request->hasfile('image'))
            { 
                $file=$request->file('image');
                //Get File name with the extension
                $fileWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                //Get Just File Name
                $filename = pathinfo($fileWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                //Get Just Extension
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                //Filename to store
                $nameoffile = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
                //Upload Image
                $path = $file->move(public_path('images'),$nameoffile); 

                $path = $nameoffile;
            }  
            else
            {
                $path=null;
            }
        }
        elseif(!empty($question->imgpath) && $request->hasfile('image'))
        {
            $file=$request->file('image');
            $fileWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = pathinfo($fileWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $nameoffile = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            $path = $file->move(public_path('images'),$nameoffile); 
            $path = $nameoffile;
        }
        else
        {
           $path=$question->imgpath;
        }
```

Comment: A question like this might be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new trait or function in your model class and can use that in your controller . Like this

In your `Quiz.php` just create a new function called `fileUpload()`

```
php artisan fileUpload($data) 
    {
      $file=$data;
      //Get File name with the extension
      $fileWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
      //Get Just File Name
      $filename = pathinfo($fileWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
      //Get Just Extension
      $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
      //Filename to store
      $nameoffile = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
      //Upload Image
      $path = $file->move(public_path('images'),$nameoffile); 

      $path = $nameoffile;

      return $path;
    }
```

And in your controller in `store()` and `update()` you can just do this

```
    if(is_null($question->imgpath))
    {
        if($request->hasfile('image'))
        {  
            $path = $quiz->fileUpload($request->file('image'));
        }  
        else
        {
            $path=null;
        }
    }
```